# Installing GDB in Python Slim image in Docker

Tags: docker, gdb

I need to install pip cfgrib in my Docker container in order to read .grib files using xarray. In order to install cfgrib I need eccodes. To get eccodes, apparently I need a fortran compiler which requires gdb.

Installing gdb is proving problematic. Following the documentation [here](http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-install-gdb) I am getting an error which I don't entirely understand:

```
amd64-linux-nat.c:248:1: error: conflicting types for ‘ps_get_thread_area’
 ps_get_thread_area (const struct ps_prochandle *ph,
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from gdb_proc_service.h:30,
                 from amd64-linux-nat.c:30:
/usr/include/proc_service.h:72:17: note: previous declaration of ‘ps_get_thread_area’ was here
 extern ps_err_e ps_get_thread_area (struct ps_prochandle *,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: Leaving directory '/gdb-7.11/gdb'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1141: amd64-linux-nat.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/gdb-7.11'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9157: all-gdb] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:847: all] Error 2
```

And including my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt update && \
    apt-get install -y cmake libgtest-dev libboost-test-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
COPY eccodes-2.18.0-Source.tar.gz .

# install gdb - this is where I am getting a problem
ADD "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.11.tar.gz" gdb-7.11.tar.gz 
RUN tar -xvzf gdb-7.11.tar.gz &&\
    cd gdb-7.11 && ./configure && make &&\
    make install &&\
    cd ..\

#install fortran compiler
RUN apt-get install -y gcc-gfortran 
RUN tar -xzf  eccodes-2.18.0-Source.tar.gz
RUN cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=. ../eccodes-2.18.0-Source

RUN pip install xarray

RUN pip install eccodes-python

RUN pip install cfgrib
```

Comment: Your link led you to download gdb 7.11, which predates Debian Buster (which is what python:3.7-slim downloads). It looks like this declaration conflict appeared when a Linux header file was changed, and was fixed in gdb by changing `ps_get_thread_area (const struct ps_prochandle *ph` to `ps_get_thread_area (struct ps_prochandle *ph`. Can you use a more recent version of gdb such as 9.2? Alternatively, you can edit (using, say, sed) amd64-linux-nat.c to make that change.